# JS Setting background position to a random number from an array

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a html slot machine and I have each symbol placed using background-position. I don't know why my JS is not working. I have an array with all the bg positions and a variable which gets a random number from there...if I console log this variable it will show the random number, but the bg position is not changing.

```
        function spin2() {
          let bgPos = [120, 190, 260, 320, 390, 460, 520, 590, 650, 715, 780, 845, 910, 975, 1040, 1105, 1170, 1235, 1300, 1365, 1430, 1495];
          let randombgPos = bgPos[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgPos.length)];
          return randombgPos;
          document.getElementById('strip1').style.backgroundPosition = "0px" + randombgPos + "px";
        }
```

Comment: simple typo: `"0px" + randombgPos + "px" === "0px120px"` Add a space... and the return is before the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues with the code

```
function spin2() {
  let bgPos = [120, 190, 260, 320, 390, 460, 520, 590, 650, 715, 780, 845, 910, 975, 1040, 1105, 1170, 1235, 1300, 1365, 1430, 1495];
  let randombgPos = bgPos[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgPos.length)];
  return randombgPos;  <-- exits function
  document.getElementById('strip1').style.backgroundPosition = "0px" + randombgPos + "px";  <-- generates wrong string for position.
}
```

with the adjustments:

```
function spin2() {
  let bgPos = [120, 190, 260, 320, 390, 460, 520, 590, 650, 715, 780, 845, 910, 975, 1040, 1105, 1170, 1235, 1300, 1365, 1430, 1495];
  let randombgPos = bgPos[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgPos.length)];
  document.getElementById('strip1').style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + randombgPos + "px";
  return randombgPos;
}
```